# How to select 1st item in selenium using document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath

Trying to identify the Active check box[Not the Active text]. I tried the following 2 items[which did not work]:

```
//div[@class='b-hide-xs']//input[@id='active-filter']/following-sibling::i

(//span[text()='Status']/../..//div[@class='b-ml-large']//span[text()='Active'])[2]
```

[image]
    
    
    
    
    Active

I noticed this 1 worked: div.b-hide-xs i.b-custom

Problem: this selects 3 items Active, Expired and Inactive. Is there anything like array that can be used so that I can select any one of those 3, for example (div.b-hide-xs i.b-custom)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEnAf.jpg)

```
<div class="b-checkbox">
<label for="expired-filter" class="">
<input type="checkbox" id="expired-filter" value="on">
<i class="b-custom"></i>
</label>
</div>
<div class="b-checkbox">
<label for="inactive-filter" class="">
<input type="checkbox" id="inactive-filter" value="on">
<i class="b-custom"></i>
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: share HTML code for these three check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the elements in a list and use basic array indexing to access them:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.b-hide-xs i.b-custom")

elements[0].click()

elements[1].click()

# etc..
```

Or:

```
for element in element:
    element.click()
```